# Telegram bot private message

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

How do I process the private message I receive with a telegram bot?
.

When someone sends me a message, I want to send that person a message. But the message must have come to me.I tried to create a new bot and listen to the private messages I received, but I failed.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please have a look at [this guide on how to ask good quesitons](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Since you tagged the `python-telegram-bot` library, please also have a look at [this PTB-specfic guide](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Ask-Right).